# Recurring tasks for Care Plans in Health Cloud

Tags: health-cloud, task-recurrence, recurring

Is there a way to facilitate recurring tasks (object: Care Plan Template Task) under Care Plan- Problems and Goals? This is within Health Cloud.

For example let's say for a physiotherapy treatment plan you have a task that is to be repeated daily, weekly or fortnightly, rather than building in dozens of repeated Tasks into the Care Plan Template, you have one with some recurring settings that each time the task gets completed another is generated for the next day or week. Or any kind of solution for that.

An option might be to utilise the standard Task recurring/series feature with Care plans.

When we create a Care plan from a template it maps the data we built into the Care Plan Template Tasks across to the actual patient care plan with standard Task records (CarePlanTemplateTask__c -> Task), and similar with the Problems and Goals (CarePlanTemplateGoal__c -> CarePlanGoal__c. CarePlanTemplateProblem__c -> CarePlanProblem__c).

Standard Task object has fields for recurrence: IsRecurrence, RecurrenceInterval, RecurrenceType, amongst others.

Is there a way to map the fields, if we were to replicate the fields onto the CarePlanTemplateTask__c object?